# Model performance plotting: MAE plot for regression model [Regression equivalent of ROC plot]

Tags: r, regression, data-science

I have a regression model for determining rentals, and the prediction is the number of rentals by hour, not a 0/1 binary outcome.

Therefore for a performance metric I am principally looking at the Mean Absolute Error (MAE).

My question is, is there a way to graphically plot the MAE in R? I am essentially looking for an MAE version of the ROCR package.

My dataset also needs to look at how the model's performance varies the further it predicts into the future, so I'd like to plot the MAE of the regression prediction on the test data against the time it is predicting.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply calculate MAE yourself.  Here is a simple example that includes a rolling calculation of MAE. It is not very meaningful in this context, but maybe useful for your purpose:

```
library(dplyr)

MyData <- iris %>% select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length,Petal.Width)

MyModel <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., MyData)

MyDf <- data.frame(Observation = MyData$Sepal.Length,
                   Predictions = predict(MyModel),
                   CumMeanAbsError = cumsum(abs(MyData$Sepal.Length-predict(MyModel)))/as.integer(row.names(MyData)))
```